# WPF - Get Position of Caret in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a "smart" editor in my application and a drop down should come down whenever a specific word comes up. How do I get the `point` object or position of the caret so I can launch the `context menu`? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `richTextBox.CaretPosition.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward)`. This should give you a `Rect` indicating the position just forward of the caret. Relative to the RichTextBox.